# PHP Integers with leading zeros

Tags: php, string, integer

Particularly, 08 and 09 have caused me some major trouble. Is this a PHP bug?

Explanation:
I have a calendar 'widget' on a couple of our client's sites, where we have a HTML hard-coded calendar (I know a PHP function can generate n number of months, but the boss man said 'no').

Within each day, there is a PHP function to check for events on that day, passing the current day of the month like so:

```
<td valign="top">01<?php printShowLink(01, $events) ?></td>
```

$events is an array of all events on that month, and the function checks if an event is on that day:

```
function printShowLink($dayOfMonth, $eventsArray) {
    $show = array();
    $printedEvent = array();
    $daysWithEvents = array();

    foreach($eventsArray as $event) {

    if($dayOfMonth == $event['day'] && !in_array($event['id'], $printedEvent)){

        if(in_array($event['day'], $daysWithEvents)) {
            echo '<hr class="calendarLine" />';
        } else {
            echo '<br />';
        }

        $daysWithEvents[] = $event['day']; // string parsed from timestamp

        if($event['linked'] != 1) {
            echo '<div class="center cal_event '.$event['class'].'" id="center"><span title="'.$event['title'].'" style="color:#666666;">'.$event['shorttitle'].'</span></div>';
            $printedEvent[] = $event['id'];
        } else {
            echo '<div class="center cal_event '.$event['class'].'" id="center"><a href="event.php?id='.$event['id'].'" title="'.$event['title'].'">'.$event['shorttitle'].'</a></div>';
            $printedEvent[] = $event['id'];
            }
        }
    }

}
```

On the 8th and 9th, no events will show up. Passing a string of the day instead of a zero-padded integer causes the same problem.

The solution is as what is should have been in the first place, a non-padded integer. However, my question is, have you seen this odd behavior with 08 and/or 09?

I googled this and couldn't find anything out there.

Comment: Can you convert to integers using `intval()` function to fix it?

Comment: @Teddy - I think I tried that, but I'm not sure. Considering PHP is loosely-typed, wouldn't I get the exact same result?

I'm going to have to run some tests when I get the chance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quote it.  `0123` without quotes is octal in PHP.  [It's in the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php)

```
$ php -r 'echo 01234, "\n01234\n";'
668
01234
$
```

So you should change your code to

```
<td valign="top">01<?php printShowLink('01', $events) ?></td>
```

Answer (score 3):

It's been a while since I've had to wade through so much PHP been doing mostly Javascript for 3 years.  But 08 and 09 being a problem makes me think: they could be getting treated as octal (base 8), and the digits 8 and 9 do *not* exist in octal.