# PHP in_array ignoring leading zeros

Tags: php

I have an array of 0845 numbers that is being searched via in_array for a specific numbers. For some reason, omitting the leading zero from the needle returns a false positive:

```
$numbers = array(
  '08451234567',
  '08452345678',
  '08453456789',
  '08454567890',
  ...
);

var_dump(in_array('08451234567', $numbers)); //(Boolean) TRUE - Right
var_dump(in_array('8451234567', $numbers)); //(Boolean) TRUE - Wrong
```

I have tried casting the values in the array as strings, but that did not work.

What is going on, and how do I fix it?

[edit]

Added quote around my needles

Comment: And `var_dump(in_array('8451234567', $numbers));` and `var_dump(in_array('08451234567', $numbers));` ???

Comment: And what happens when you `var_dump(08451234567)`;

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use strict comparision

> bool in_array ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict = FALSE ] )

Use

```
var_dump(in_array("08451234567", $numbers,true)); //(Boolean) true - OK
var_dump(in_array("8451234567", $numbers,true)); //(Boolean) false - OK
```

Why

```
var_dump(08451234567); // returns 0 because its octal 
var_dump((int) "08451234567"); // returns 8451234567
var_dump((float) "08451234567"); // returns  8451234567
```

Only

```
var_dump("08451234567" === "08451234567"); // returns true
```

[See Live Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/6rOnmZ)

Answer (score 4):

> Quote it. 0123 without quotes is octal in PHP. [It's in the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php)

This has been [answered in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450932/php-integers-with-leading-zeros) before.

Answer (score -1):

Wrap the number with `'` else the leading `0` will be ignored and the value will be converted to an integer.

```
var_dump(in_array('08451234567', $numbers));
var_dump(in_array('8451234567',  $numbers));
```